# Prove if $k^\text{th}$ derivative of an entire function $f$ is polynomial, then $f$ itself is polynomial. Where's my mistake?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, power-series, taylor-expansion, entire-functions

The exact wording of the question is as follows:

> Let $f$ be an entire function. Suppose there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $k^\text{th}$ derivative $f^{(k)}$ is a polynomial. Prove that $f$ is a polynomial.

Following the Taylor series representation of an arbitrary function $f(z) = \sum_{k \geq 0} c_k z^k$ and taking its derivative format as written in the textbook as an assumption, I provided the following as the solution:

> Let $f^{(k)}(z) = \sum_{n\geq k} n(n-1)\ldots (n-k+1) c_k z^{n-k}$ and
>   let $d_n = n(n-1)\ldots (n-k+1) c_k $. If $f^{(k)}$ is polynomial then
>   $d_{k_0}$ is constant for each $k_0 \geq k$. Then $\underbrace{\int
>  \ldots \int}_k f^{(k)} dz \ldots dz = \underbrace{\int \ldots \int}_k
>  \sum_{n\geq k} d_n z^{n-k} dz \ldots dz = \sum_{n\geq k} 
>  \underbrace{\int \ldots \int}_k d_n z^{n-k} dz \ldots dz$
>
> Since sum of polynomials is polynomial and $f = \underbrace{\int
>  \ldots \int}_k f^{(k)} dz \ldots dz$, then $f$ is polynomial.

I was told the proof is wrong because I needed to show the Taylor series is finite; in other words, say $d_{k_0} = 0$ as opposed to just being a constant.

But now that I'm thinking about it:

1. What I said about $d_{k_0}$ is not wrong but it is redundant, since the coefficients of $z$ are constant by definition of the Taylor series.
2. I don't really see why it's necessary to write that the Taylor series is finite - even though it necessarily is. I'm showing it takes finitely many antiderivatives (i.e. $k$ many) of $f^{(k)}$ (which is assumed to be polynomial). Since I'm just adding and integrating terms of the Taylor series of some polynomial function (i.e. $f^{(k)}$), whatever property needed by a Taylor series to represent a polynomial function (i.e. $f$) must automatically be satisfied.

I'd very much appreciate it if anyone could specify my mistake.

Comment: To be honest I don't see the problem. You have that $f$ equals the antiderivarive plus a polynomial because of the integration constants. The antiderivarive is a polynomial, so you are done.

Comment: Mistake or not, using Taylor series for this feels like the long way around, inviting worry about convergence that could have been avoided. It would feel much more direct to use induction on $k$. For $k=1$, integrate the polynomial $f'(z)$ symbolically to get $g(z)$, also a polynomial. Since $(f-g)'=0$ and $f(z_0)=g(z_0)$ if you choose the right constant of integration, you must have $f-g=0$, so $f$ is the polynomial $g$.

Comment: First show that if $f^{(k)} = 0$ then $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks. But this was an exam question for which I received 2 out of 10. I need to see where my mistake is because (i) I need to learn it and (ii) if there's no mistake, then the grading is problematic.

Comment: But your argument is somehow unclear. You can do it the opposite way. Assume the form of the derivative and integrate to get the function. I guess another way is Cauchy integral.

Comment: Ah, you have to understand that with exam questions there is a marking scheme and the marks have to be consistent. So our opinion doesn't matter if this is the way it was marked for everyone.

Comment: @tst That makes sense and it's fine for me to even have it completely rejected on the basis of being unclear or something equivalent. But the invalidity of my solution should be demonstrable irrespective of the scheme.

Comment: I think the actual problem is that you didn't really use the fact that the $k$th derivative has finite Taylor series. You have written only infinite sums.

Comment: @copper.hat Do you mean showing for a polynomial function like $f^{(k)}$ there'd be $m \geq 1$ such that $f^{(k+m)} = 0$ and then integrate $(m+n)$ times to get $f$? If so, that makes sense, but I don't see why would I need to do that as I still don't understand why I can't go from $f^{(k)}$ to $f$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82330/discussion-between-tst-and-atonal).

Answer (score 2):

> If $f^{(k)}$ is polynomial then $d_{k_0}$ is constant for each $k_0
> > k$.

At this point you already started on the wrong path. Note that the series 
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty 2 x^k$$
for example satisfies your condition, but is not a polynomial!

Since you try to deduce from here that your function is a polynomial, your argument must be wrong, and here is why:

\smallskip

> Since sum of polynomials is polynomial and $f=f = \underbrace{\int  \ldots \int}_k f^{(k)} dz \ldots dz$, then f is polynomial.

Here you make the second mistake. It is true that a **finite** sum of polynomials is a polynomial, BUT your sum is

> $$\sum_{n\geq k}   \underbrace{\int \ldots \int}_k d_n z^{n-k} dz \ldots dz$$

is an infinite sum, and an infinite sum of polynomials is not always a polynomial.

Comment: Yes. I predicted one may raise these two issues. I addressed them in the two points I had at the end of the post. 

My whole point is that if I have the Taylor series representing a polynomial function (f^k), then adding finitely many terms to it or integrating them so that I could get (f) wouldn't change the fact that it's a polynomial: Any property that a series must have for it to represent a polynomial would still be kept, including being finite. So since the series for f^k is polynomial (and is necessarily finite), the sum would still be valid. Isn't it?

Comment: @Atonal You are right about the comment, but that is not what you wrote in your solution. The simple fact that now you can explain how to solve the problem does not make the different answer you wrote correct.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, then $a_n = {1 \over n!} f^{(n)}(0)$.

If $p$ is a polynomial, then $p^{(m)} = 0$ for some $m$. Since $f^{(k)}$ is a polynomial,
there is some $m$ such that $f^{(k+m)} = 0$. Hence $a_n =0$ for $n \ge k+m$. Then
$f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{k+m-1} a_n z^n$, which is a polynomial.

**Another approach**:

If $p$ is a polynomial, then $q(z) = c+\int_0^z p(w)dw$ is a polynomial.

Suppose $f^{(k)}$ is a polynomial. Then the fundamental theorem of calculus 
gives us $f^{(k-1)}(z) = f^{(k-1)}(0) + \int_0^z f^{(k)}(w) dw$, and so
$f^{(k-1)}$ is a polynomial. Continue by induction to get that $f$ si a
polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

I would prove it
by induction on $k$.

Base case - 
$k=1$.

If
$f'(x)$
is a polynomial
then
$f'(x)
=\sum_{j=0}^d a_jx^j
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=f(0)+\int_0^x f'(t) dt\\
&=f(0)+\int_0^x (\sum_{j=0}^d a_jt^j) dt\\
&=f(0)+\sum_{j=0}^d a_j\int_0^x t^j dt\\
&=f(0)+\sum_{j=0}^d a_j\dfrac{x^{j+1}}{j+1}\\
\end{array}
$

is a polynomial.

If true for $k$ then
if
$f^{(k+1)}(x)$
is a polynomial then
$f'(x)$
is a polynomial
by the induction hypothesis
for $k$
since
$(f'(x))^{(k)}
=f^{(k+1)}(x)
$.
Therefore
$f(x)$
is a polynomial
by the base case
with $k=1$.